# server is disconnected while executing impala query

Tags: server, connection, impala

I connect to my server via ssh, and I tried to run query with impala-shell on server like below:

```
impala-shell -B --output_delimiter=',' -o test_file.txt -q " my query "
```

Data size is quite big and total row number is about 500,000,000.
But after few hours, server is disconnected and result file has only 470,000,000 rows.

Strange thing is when query ends successfully, I always saw message like below:

```
Fetched 10438968 row(s) in 433.84s
```

but there was no message. I think server is disconnected while query is running.
Actually, the server is set up for auto-logout(timeout value is 300). Is this problem? Can the server disconnect even though the query is running?

Comment: `Can the server disconnect even though the query is running?` - possible. Sometime query shows complete but in the backend data dup still running. so pls check the file after 1 hour and see if any changes. You may need to split into multiple files.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I clearly understand. thanks a lot!